# forecast results for a specific vector x using statsmodels linear regressions

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I've successfully built a model using OLS for a large number of data.

```
results = smf.ols(formula='ind ~ Age + C(County) + C(Class)',  data=df).fit()
```

I'd like to implement a method that allows the user to input a vector `X` and have it return a `y` based on the regression. I looked into "predict" and "forecast" features of statsmodels but it didn't seem to be what I was looking for.

So for example, what I'd like to do is:

```
 ## Although the following is wrong, It shows what I'm trying to do:
 def forecast_y(X):
      return results.forecast(X) 


 ## example:
 print forecast_y([1, 3, 4]) 
 # the model should return
 4.53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting that right, you don't want the in-sample prediction of `y`, which is why you don't want to use the `predict` method; instead you just want to be able to plug in arbitrary `x` values and get a value for `y` based on the predicted coefficients ?

If that's the case, continuing from your example:

```
params = results.params   #vector of your coefficients
arbitrary_x = np.array([.5, .5, .5...]) #whatever x values you want to test, with the constant first

assert(len(params) == len(arbitrary_x))

arbitrary_y = (params * arbitrary_x).sum()
```

I'll leave understanding the implications of this to the reader, but do use with care.

Comment: That worked! Thanks :). Question for you. Is there a way to determine the "accuracy" of an individual prediction?

Comment: Well,for within the sample you can just do `results.pvalues'.  However, pvalues *assume* you are getting the model right, so you have to be careful trying to interpret them at all if you're experimenting with your model.

Comment: I'm quiet happy with my R2 = 0.6; however, I wonder if the model is better at predicting the "lower" values than the higher values and in that case does the probability that an arbitrary_Y forecast is accurate goes up or down?

Comment: Try putting your data in scatter plots, one for each x value paried with your y.  It's always a good practice when getting to know your data, and lots of things can become obvious at a glance that are very difficult to test for statistically.

Comment: Ya, my comment was based on a scatter plot. the data "looks" exponential in nature y = me(cXi + bi) . I'm trying to build a model that fora given vector X, what is the y and how confident are we in the prediction

Comment: `results.predict(x_new)` does exactly the same as the answer, i.e. calculate x_new dot results.params for a linear models like OLS. `forecast` is only used for time series models like ARMA.

Comment: @user333700 do you want to submit a subsequent answer and I can perhaps accept it if that is the more correct method to do things?